# CNTK Windows install - $SourceFile cannot be retrieved

Tags: cntk

Apologies if this was already addressed but I cannot find it.
I am trying to setup CNTK (on Windows 7 and 10) from:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/Setup-Windows-Binary-Script

and while trying the initial install.bat in Step 2 throws the following error after "Performing download operations". Any thoughts anyone?

FYI This is from the 64-bit, CPU only version

[Fatal Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPXEg.png) (actual error pasted below)

```
Fatal error during script execution!
 System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: The variable '$SourceFile' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
   at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext funcContext, Exception exception)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0)
   at System.Management.Automation.PSScriptCmdlet.RunClause(Action`1 clause, Object dollarUnderbar, Object inputToProcess)
   at System.Management.Automation.PSScriptCmdlet.DoEndProcessing()
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.Complete()

Error during install operation
```